# Single Page Application? Login Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, authentication

I'm a little new to programming and I'm still beginning on working with a lot of the languages.

Currently, I'm working on a project that requires me to create a login page. With a successful login, the page will change to an "Account Info" page; however, this has to be a single page application. My professor specified that the server will have no concept of "page", and that moving from "Login" to "AccountInfo" will not change the page/URL.

How do I go about calling this? We've done introduction into Angular JS, but he's never done a tutorial on single page applications.

My .js for the login looks like this:

```
Home.LoginClick = function () {

    $.ajax({

        url: "Home/Login",

        data: {

            Username: $(".Username").val(),

            Password: $(".Password").val(),

        },

        success: function (result) { alert(result);
            if (deserializedData.Message == "Success")
                Home.ChangeToAccountInfo();
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Can you add your html /css to this so its easier to suggest

Comment: Not a helpful comment for you regarding your exact question (sorry for that), but I'm not sure if being plunged into AngularJS (of all things) is such a good idea when you just start to learn about programming in general (as you indicated). Would a good, solid understanding of JavaScript as a language and 'the way the web works' as a concept not be a better starting point before engaging is these abstract and higher level frameworks?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the correct Angular approach is, but here's one approach: create an HTML element that holds a user's "account info" (like a `<div>` or `<article>`, etc.), and have it conditionally display on the screen using `ng-if` if the user is authenticated and/or the website is in some "state".  You could use the controller's $scope to hold the website's state - e.g. the current "page" that should be displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Single Page application means that the client loads all the HTML in one shot, thus preventing your browser to refresh the page every time you click somewhere or go a different page. You can witness this in action by going into most websites.

It is considered best practices to use services for back end interaction. Therefore you should create a Auth. service managing your login. Create a function login - and logout. and then inject that service in your controller associated with the view thats displays the login form.

You should upon submission of the form call this login function. you can use ng-submit. after submitting the form the function that you injected in your controller will check with you backend to see if the user exist or not and then you can redirect the user toward the page you want.

You should look into the ui router for more details about how to handles your routes.